# iTunes Eject Button

Tags: itunes

Do i need to press eject button on iTunes before unplug my USB cable?
Since after that i still want ipad able to sync via WIFI.

Or please inform what is the purpose that eject button?

It is for safely unplug USB cable from MAC or make the device is will be not anymore synchronise with iTunes?

[image: iTunes Eject Button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eject button *unmounts* the iPad (in other words, disconnects it). Yes, you should eject it first before you unplug the USB cable to ensure that it isn't in the middle of performing an operation.

If you enable automatic (instead of manual) syncing, I believe there is no need to eject.

You can certainly sync over WiFi without the iPad being plugged in via USB; that is the point of WiFi syncing, after all ;) (You do need the iPad plugged into power, though, I think).